# How do I add a linebreak in align mode?

Tags: line-breaking, align

Sorry it looks so messy, but in the code I put a line made of plus signs where I want the break. How would I do that?

```
\begin{align}  
$$\bigg|f\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)-P\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg|\leq \displaystyle \frac{1}{100}  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
\bigg| f\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)-P\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg|\leq \max_{0\leq c \leq\frac{1}{2}} \bigg|\displaystyle \frac{f^{(5)}(c)}{5!}\bigg|\displaystyle \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{5}$$  
\end{align}
```

Comment: 1. don't use $$ inside the align environment.  2. Use \\ where linebreak is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below coding for your requirement:

```
\begin{align}
& \bigg|f\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)-P\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg|\leq \displaystyle \frac{1}{100}
\\ \nonumber 
& \bigg| f\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)-P\bigg(\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg|\leq \max_{0\leq c \leq\frac{1}{2}} \bigg|\displaystyle \frac{f^{(5)}(c)}{5!}\bigg|\displaystyle \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{5}
\end{align}
```

[image]